# Stargazer options: resizebox and label

Tags: r, latex, knitr, stargazer

Is it possible to incorporate resizebox into stargazer in R?  I'm trying to create a table that is too wide to fit, even on landscape perspective.  I manually added resizebox{\textwidth}{!} { \begin{tabular} \end{tabular} } to the .tex file, and I like how it looks.  However, I'd like for my .Rnw file to be complete, so that I can generate pdf perfectly without additional changes to the .tex file.

On a related note, stargazer causes pdflatex to output multiple warnings due to it including \label{} when no label is specified.  These don't affect the pdf's creation, but they cause confusion when there are other errors present.

Again, I can manually delete these lines from the .tex file, or assign label names.  However, I would like to simply tell stargazer not to include this line at all.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution yet? Facing the same problem.

Comment: I was never able to find a better solution.

Comment: Would you be willing to connect with me on LinkedIn  https://www.linkedin.com/in/scott-boston/?  Thanks for you help again with that geopandas question.

Comment: @Scott sure, just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found is to use set the stargazer option float to FALSE and then use cat() to manually put the scalebox in the float environment; for example:

```
<< results='asis', echo = FALSE>>=

cat("\\begin{table}[!htbp]")
cat("\\centering")
cat("\\caption{OLS Regression Results by Metal Level}")
cat("\\label{OLS}")
cat("\\scalebox{.8}{")

stargazer(models$model1OLS,
          float = FALSE)

cat("}") # for the end of the scalebox
cat("\\end{table}")

@
```

Note that you will also have to manually label, center, and caption the table. This will almost surely work with using resizebox instead of scalebox, but I haven't tried.

Comment: This is very similar to Nicolas' approach.  Do you find that there are benefits to one versus the other?

Comment: No real advantage or disadvantage, just slightly more readable (to me) code at the cost of more typing. I do a fair amount of collaboration with people who are very familiar with Latex, but not with R (most economists use Stata) and I've found this way easier to explain exactly what's going on.

Comment: it's indeed more readable for R-people thus preferable. I wonder if stargazer will come in a future version with a rescale option (as all the other latex options such as positioning etc are implemented)

Answer (score 5):

It's not ideal, but you can manually manipulate the LaTeX code output from stargazer with `capture.output()` and `gsub()`.

```
table <- capture.output({ # Store the stargazer output in a string
  stargazer(iris, header=F) # e.g.
})
table <- gsub("\\begin{tabular}","\\resizebox{0.9\\textwidth}{!}{\\begin{tabular}", table,fixed=T)
table <- gsub("\\end{tabular}","\\end{tabular}}", table,fixed=T)
cat(table)
```

You can also extract that procedure into a method if you need it in more than one place.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas for this smart answer. Little question though, how do we export the cat(table) file to a latex file ?

Comment: depends on your setup, but you would put the `cat(table)` in the same place you would write `stargazer(...)`. e.g. in a Rnw file: `<<table-code, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
cat(table)
@`

Answer (score 1):

To answer part 2 of your question, you can use `label` to label tables. This way you don't have to manually delete the empty \label{} from the `.tex` file. You will also be able to reference your tables using \ref{your.table.label}.

```
stargazer(df, title = "Statistical Summary", label="your.table.label", table.placement = "H")
```