# How to resize tables generated by Stargazer in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, beamer, stargazer

I included `resize.height=0.5,resize.width=0.5` in the code chunk, but still can't resize the table generated by stargazer. Can anyone tell me why?

My code chunk options look like this:
`echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,results='asis',resize.height=0.5,resize.width=0.5}`

The stargazer codes are like this:

```
stargazer(did.student,student.control.kmt,student.control.neu,student.control.dpp,header = FALSE,
          title="DD Model",
          covariate.labels = c("Treatment","group","Treatment*group"),
          dep.var.labels = "attitude",
          column.labels   = c("","party1","Independent","party2"),
          label = "DiD-students")
```

Would appreciate any help!

--
Forgot to mention - I'm using beamer with the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I kind of solve the problem myself:

To adjust table size with stargazer, you can change the font size `font.size=`, make the Stargazer single row `single.row = TRUE` and change the space between columns `column.sep.width = "1pt"` in `stargazer()`.

Though [the link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507191/automatically-adjust-latex-table-width-to-fit-pdf-using-knitr-and-rstudio) suggests using `print(stargazer(),scalebox='0.7')`, it doesn't work for me perhaps because I'm using Markdown with Beamer, but I'm not sure. Would still love to have more contribution on this.

I was hoping for a more straightforward answer, but this works!

Answer (score 5):

[This comment on GitHub](https://github.com/HertieDataScience/SyllabusAndLectures/issues/85#issuecomment-305958129) inspired me to implement `\resizebox{}` into `stargazer()`. You can use `resizebox.stargazer()` to specify the size of the table outputted from `stargazer()` with `tab.width` and/or `tab.height` arguments. To activate the function, you need to run the following code first:

```r
resizebox.stargazer = function(..., tab.width = "!", tab.height = "!"
                               ){
  #Activate str_which() function:
  require(stringr) 

  #Extract the code returned from stargazer()
  res = capture.output(
    stargazer::stargazer(...)
    )

  #Render the arguments:
  tab.width = tab.width
  tab.height = tab.height

  #Attach "}" between \end{tabular} and \end{table}
  res = 
    prepend(res, "}", before = length(res))

  #Input \resizebox before \begin{tabular}
  res = 
    c(res[1:str_which(res, "^\\\\begin\\{tabular\\}.*")-1],
      paste0("\\resizebox{",tab.width,"}{",tab.height,"}{%"),
      res[str_which(res, "^\\\\begin\\{tabular\\}.*"):length(res)]
      )

  #Produce the whole strings
  cat(res, sep = "\n")
}
```

You can specify the table size by e.g. `resizebox.stargazer(..., tab.width = "0.7\\textwidth")`. Note that you have to write the TeX commands from `\\` instead of `\`.

Comment: Thanks! This is wonderful. However, it seems that the unmodified text goes into output file. E.g. defining `out = output.tex` does not yield a scaled table but the original one.

Answer (score 4):

I would follow @yuan-ning and manipulate the options of stargazer. Try the following for PDF output of R markdown:

```
stargazer(model_1, model_2, model_3, model_4, model_5,
          type = 'latex',
 
          header=FALSE, # to get rid of r package output text

          single.row = TRUE, # to put coefficients and standard errors on same line

          no.space = TRUE, # to remove the spaces after each line of coefficients

          column.sep.width = "3pt", # to reduce column width

          font.size = "small" # to make font size smaller

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Carlos' solution that writes the output to a LaTeX file:

```
mkTexTable <- function(..., file){

    tbl <- capture.output({
        stargazer(...)
    })    

    tbl <- gsub("\\begin{tabular}", "\\resizebox{\\textwidth}{!}{\\begin{tabular}", tbl, fixed = T)
    tbl <- gsub("\\end{tabular}", "\\end{tabular}}", tbl, fixed = T)

    fileConn <- file(file)
    writeLines(tbl, fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
}

mkTexTable(lm1, lm2, "texOutput.tex")
```

This post also provided some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018251/2289444

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with html Rmd files, you sould specify `{r, results = 'asis'}` at the beginning of the chunck and then in stargazer `type = 'html'`. That worked for me.