# How to adjust the font size of stargazer tables in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

If I am not mistaken, the font size argument in stargazer is ignored in rmarkdown documents:

Does somebody know how to fix this?
See also here
[How to resize tables generated by Stargazer in R Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245920/how-to-resize-tables-generated-by-stargazer-in-r-markdown)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library("stargazer")
m <- lm(speed~dist, cars)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
stargazer(m, type = "html", font.size="tiny", single.row = T)
stargazer(m, type = "html", font.size="Huge", single.row = T)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
print(stargazer(m, type = "html", single.row = T), scalebox='0.7')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to the end of your YAML, adjusting the font size as you wish:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
<style>
body { font-size: 20px; }
</style>
```

And the larger font will render:

[image]

Comment: sorry, i wasnt clear, I just need to change the size of the table, not of the whole document

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `font.size` argument in `stargazer` is only used when rendered in Latex.

Instead when rendering to HTML you have to add a style element to the appropriate tag, in this case `td` for the table cell, `th` for the table header, or `table` for the entire table.

After the YAML header add the following css:

```
<style>

table, th, td {
    font-size: 16px;
}

</style>
```

Or, if you want e.g. large table headers:

```
<style>

th {
    font-size: 42px;
}

td {
    font-size: 21px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is html it is necessary to have some knowledge about handling tables in html you can see [here](http://[1]:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/inXAA.png), so place the code `<font size="5" face="Courier New" >` at the top of the table.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r cars, include=F}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(cars, type = "html", out="test.html", out.header=TRUE)
```
<font size="5" face="Courier New" >
<table style="text-align:center"><tr><td colspan="8" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">Statistic</td><td>N</td><td>Mean</td><td>St. Dev.</td><td>Min</td><td>Pctl(25)</td><td>Pctl(75)</td><td>Max</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="8" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">speed</td><td>50</td><td>15.400</td><td>5.288</td><td>4</td><td>12</td><td>19</td><td>25</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">dist</td><td>50</td><td>42.980</td><td>25.769</td><td>2</td><td>26</td><td>56</td><td>120</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="8" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr></table>
````

Comment: please add some explanation to your solution.